# Is there any application that can generate waveform and sine waves of audio files?

Tags: audio, waveform, research

I'm trying to find an application that can generate waveform and sine waves of whatever audio file I input.

I require this application for my college project, it is a research on sound and mathematical patterns.

It'd be great if you guys can help me out! I've been looking for some time but can't find any.

I apologize if I posted it in the wrong place.

Comment: Most audio editors can produce such waves as they are sometimes needed to create effects. You say "of whatever audio file" so do you mean a visual representation of some audio file you already have? Same answer anyway.

Comment: I would *highly* recommend becoming **very** familiar with the Fourier transform, Laplace transform, Convolution, and all of the associated math prior to undertaking your project, if you haven't already, if you want to come up with anything original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am an engineering student my self and I use Audacity to generate Sine, Sawtooth, Square waves. It's easy as pie.

1. Download Audacity from [here](http://www.audacityteam.org/download/).
2. Open Audacity and click on Generate from the Toolbar on top.
3. Select the waveform you need, the frequency, the amplitude and duration you want it.
4. Play the track.

Answer (score 4):

Any DAW (digital audio workstation) or even most video editing software will display a waveform for the audio in a particular file.  You can not, however, make a "sine wave of whatever audio file" because the file doesn't contain a sine wave.

A sine wave is a very particular type of fixed frequency oscillation.  You would set a signal generator to a particular frequency for sinusoidal waves and it would create a sine wave at that frequency.

The waveform in an audio file for speech or music or anything like that is a much more complicated compound wave composed of many interacting frequencies.

All sound "frequencies" are simply rates of pressure change.  The "volume" or SPL (sound pressure level) of a sound is determined by the amount of air that is moved.  A loud sound moves a lot of air, a quiet sound moves a little air.  A high frequency sound moves air back and forth a lot of times per second, a low frequency sound moves the air back and forth fewer times per second.  When you combine the two, it moves the air in and out slowly for the low frequency with the high frequency causing variations along that slow oscillation because of the pressure change from the higher frequency.  It all eventually ends up picked up by our ear or a microphone which is able to make sense of the pressure changes hitting it.

A waveform is simply the graphical representation of the amount of pressure (either high or low pressure relative to still air) that is being experienced at a given moment over time.  It is the result of all the various frequencies that make up the sound you are hearing being combined.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out [SPEAR](http://www.klingbeil.com/spear/). From the website:

- SPEAR is an application for audio analysis, editing and synthesis.
  The analysis procedure (which is based on the traditional
  McAulay-Quatieri technique) attempts to represent a sound with many
  individual sinusoidal tracks (partials), each corresponding to a
  single sinusoidal wave with time varying frequency and amplitude.

Comment: You're the only one who answered the main question's wording precisely. If the software does as you say. Dunno if that's what the OP needs, but that's definitely what they asked for!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Sony Sound Forge, there's a waveform generator inside of it.
Best for you could be Audacity which is free see the [doc](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/generate_menu.html).

You could also use a synth in a DAW to generate sines even squares etc...